# wireguard /usr/sbin/resolvconf: Permission denied when running wg-quick up

Tags: linux, vpn, fedora, wireguard

I get an error `/usr/sbin/resolvconf: Permission denied` running the command `sudo wg-quick up <config>` on Fedora 33 Kernel 5.11.12-200.

Any suggestions as to how I might fix this? The command IS being run as root (tried with body sudo and sudo su) and both resolvconf and openresolvconf is installed.

wireguard-tools is at the newest version available in DNF sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Root cause is /usr/sbin/resolvconf.openresolv not having executable flag set.
Quick and dirty fix would be to just enable it:
chmod +x /usr/sbin/resolvconf.openresolv

Comment: I had this issue on Nobara Linux (just Fedora on steroids) and the above fixed the issue for me :) Thanks!